# function to remove 'comments and trackbacks are closed'

Tags: comments

Does anyone have a function I can place in my `functions.php` that will remove this? I want to avoid altering the core files. It currently says "Both comments and trackbacks are currently closed."

Comment: This question is completely Theme-dependent. What Theme are you using?

Comment: What chip is saying is that 'comments and trackbacks are closed' messages come from your theme and not core files, and if we could know the name of your theme we may be able to help you locate the lines that produce these messages.

Comment: I'm using Thematic, which uses a lot of hooks and filters. I didn't want to touch those core files either for updating purposes. That's why I was wondering if there was a solution using a function in the funtions.php file.

Comment: open comments.php file find the words 'comments and trackbacks are closed' and remove it. simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for thematic, it's inside the 'content-extensions.php' just do a search with ctrl-f and just leave the field empty

Answer (score 1):

Look in your theme comments.php file for those words to delete. If not in there, check your functions.php file.